# Is it worth reinstalling to enable AHCI on my SSD in order to improve compile performance under Visual Studio?

Tags: performance, ssd, visual-studio, c++, ahci

I am compiling to an SSD connected through SATA using IDE emulation on Windows 7.

Unfortunately, I forgot to enable AHCI when I installed, and though there are ways of performing surgery on Windows to get it to use AHCI after the fact, they do not apply to my specific situation.  I would need to wipe and reinstall the OS which is a pain.

Do any of the advantages of AHCI apply to compilation such that they could improve the compile and link time performance of my C++ applications?  I am not doing much else in the background (I've disabled indexing of the SSD).

Answer (score 7):

It's worth enabling AHCI, but there is no need to reinstall. Here's how you should do:

- If you're running XP, then install the ACHI driver from the motherboard vendor. For Windows 7 you shouldn't need to install any drivers.
- Add the following 3 lines to an empty text file:

  **Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\msahci]

  "Start"=dword:00000000**
- Save the file, in a file with the extension .reg and execute it.
- Reboot and then enable AHCI in the bios.

It works on XP, Vista and Windows 7, but if anything fails, just disable ACHI in the bios and reboot.

Answer (score 3):

I highly doubt it is worth reinstalling to enable AHCI on your SSD in order to improve compile performance under Visual Studio.

Comment: I am inclined to agree.  I can't remember ATM where I saw it, but there were some benchmarks, and it didn't seem to make that much difference according to the benchmarks.